# Error While Updating Records Through Tkinter

Tags: mysql, tkinter, sql-update

In My Table named TCL in MySQL, I am able to Insert the Records, but while updating it I am getting the following error:-

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sapna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 489, in 
cmd_query
raw_as_string=raw_as_string)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Duplicate entry '3211' for key 'tcl.PRIMARY'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sapna\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\sapna\Desktop\SAMARTH.py", line 381, in uprec
libcur.execute(update)
File "C:\Users\sapna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 266, in 
execute
raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
File "C:\Users\sapna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 492, in 
cmd_query
sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '3211' for key 'tcl.PRIMARY'
```

Here's the coding

```
def uprec():
    b1=bn.get()
    b2=bi.get()
    b3=au.get()
    b4=D.get()
    b5=DO.get()
    b6=RE.get()
    b7=var1.get()
    b8=RN.get()
    b9=A.get()
    bn.delete(0,END)
    bi.delete(0,END)
    au.delete(0,END)
    D.delete(0,END)
    DO.delete(0,END)
    RE.delete(0,END)
    RN.delete(0,END)
    A.delete(0,END)
    update="UPDATE TCL SET Book_id='%s',Book_name='%s',Author='%s',DOI='%s',DOR='%s',Reissues='%s',Recipients_Name='%s',Address='%s',Genre='%s'"%(b2,b1,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9)
    libcur.execute(update)
    mydb.commit()
    mydb.close()
```

where bn,bi,au,D,DO,RE,RN and A are the variables assigned to the Entry widget and var1 is for the dropdown list. I am not able to understand what should I do.

Comment: Your update statement will update all records in `TCL` table because there is no `WHERE` clause.  You should add a `WHERE` clause and use `Book_id` as the filter.  Suggest you to study more on SQL, otherwise you will corrupt your database like this UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL `UPDATE` statement without `WHERE` clause will update all records in a table.  If there is column set as `PRIMARY KEY`, duplicate exception will be raised.

You should add a `WHERE` clause and use the `PRIMARY KEY` column as filter (I think for your case should be `Book_id`) as below:

```py
update = "UPDATE TCL SET Book_name=%s, Author=%s, DOI=%s, DOR=%s, Reissues=%s, Recipients_Name=%s, Address=%s, Genre=%s WHERE Book_id=%s"
libcur.execute(update, (b1, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b2))
```

Note that placeholders are used instead of string substitution.

Comment: So is '%s' same as %s ?

Comment: @CoolCloud When `%s` is used as placeholders, it should not be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: I agree, but in many textbooks ive seen it use '%s', ive never tried it on, does it give error?

Comment: Using placeholders, the driver will perform the type checking for you.  If the column is of type string, it will surround the data by quotes automatically.  So if `'%s'` is used, the final result is `''abc''` or `'"abc"'` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the update statement, there is no `where` clause. Only if you specify which record should be updated using the `where` clause will your code work.